# e.keychar and e.handled not a member of system.eventargs for KeyPress?

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing an assignment out of my text book (not homework) and it told me to plug this code in to only allow letters and the `backspace key` into the text box. I would like to think this textbook isn't wrong but I'm getting the error

`"'KeyChar' is not a member of 'System.EventArgs'"`

as well as

`"'Handled' is not a member of 'System.EventArgs'"`

Heres the code:

```
Private Sub txtLetter_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtLetter.TextChanged
    'Allows only letters and the backspace key

    If e.KeyChar Like "[!A-Za-z]" AndAlso
        e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The textbook is wrong.  Replace "EventArgs" with "KeyPressEventArgs".  And practice adding event handlers yourself instead of copying a book.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a book.

Comment: oh, didnt know you could do that.  Thanks for the timely response Hans!

Comment: shoot now its telling me "Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs'".  So confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your method indicates that you're handling a `KeyPress` event but the `Handles` clause actually specifies that it's handling the `TextChanged` event.  Change the type of the `e` parameter as suggested and also change the event being handled to `KeyPress`.  As suggested, in future, use the IDE to create your event handlers or, at the very least, read code that you copy from elsewhere to make sure that it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If this comes up, I found the solution-Add: "System.Windows.Forms.KeyPress" to get rid of the wiggles. This should do the trick. If it doesn't, re-check the code for why your errors are still there.